# (Oracle)When open a view it says insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle

Three days ago, I created another user, it's ok. Now I create another user, not working. I don't know what I missed.

This time I did:

```
CREATE USER TESTDB identified by N2dTlOBFRZ9x;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO TESTDB;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO TESTDB;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO TESTDB;
GRANT CREATE TABLE to TESTDB;
GRANT CREATE VIEW to TESTDB;
```

I can create a view, named viewTest, save it.

TESTDB viewTest

```
select * from PRODDB.employee
```

Then open viewTest, it says insufficient privileges.

---

I have another user. let's call it PRODDB. This is online database
The user I created 3 days ago, is OKDB.
Today I created one another, TESTDB.

In OKDB, I created a view (viewTest) and I can open it.
select * from PRODDB.employee;

But in TESTDB, cannot open.

Comment: It sounds like you are working with two users, correct? How are you opening the view- are you just trying to select from it? If so, which user are you trying to query the view with - the user that you created the view with, or the second user?

For example, if you have User1 and User2, create the view under User2, then User1 won't be able to select from the view until you grant the correct privilege(s) - 'grant select on User2.view to User1' and then User1 will be able to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the update! I believe this is a permissions issue.

> In OKDB, I created a view and I can open it. select * from
>   PRODDB.employee;
>
> But in TESTDB, cannot open.

So in this example, there are three users: 1. `PRODDB`, 2. `OKDB`, and 3. `TESTDB`.

The view is named `Employee` and was created under the `PRODDB` schema; `PRODDB.EMPLOYEE`.

If `OKDB` can query `PRODDB.EMPLOYEE`, one of two things have to be true. Either: 1. `OKDB` was granted privileges on `PRODDB.EMPLOYEE` directly (e.g. `grant select on PRODDB.EMPLOYEE to OKDB;`), **or** 2. `OKDB` has elevated privileges through a role that enables the user to query that view (e.g. `grant DBA to OKDB`, which will allow `OKDB` to query any table in the database.)

If `TESTDB` can't query the view, I would bet that the necessary privileges have not been granted to the user. To fix this, I would recommend checking the privileges and roles that have been granted to the `OKDB` user and then granting the same privilege(s) to `TESTDB`. If this is something work related, you may have to work with another DBA if you do not have permission to issue grants.

Comment: The view is not named employee, it's viewTest, inside OKDB and TESTDB. And I use Navicat.

Comment: Ahh ok. So, each schema has viewTest - that would mean OKDB.viewTest, TESTDB.viewTest, and PRODDB.viewTest. They should all be able to query the view in their own schema, however, if you want it so that each schema can view the others' .viewTest, you will have to grant them privileges. e.g. grant select on PRODDB.viewTest to OKDB; grant select on PRODDB.viewTest to TESTDB; grant select on TESTDB.viewTest to OKDB; grant select on TESTDB.viewTest to OKDB; so on and so forth. Once the grants are in place, each schema will be able to query the views that are housed in the others.

Comment: I find another method: GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO TESTDB;